# is oAuth possible for C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a windows application, developed in C#. where I need to perform Google oAuth so I'll get their profile. I don't want to ask the user to enter their Google Username and Password in my windows application (and of course users don't want that).

How can I do that ?

I tried
1.) Able to open Google Authentication page from my windows application, but can't figure it out how to get access token passed to my windows application.

Any inputs / suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a webBrowser control in you application. You can then let the user log in via the webBrowser control. You can then query the webBrowser control for the data.

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for is called [2-legged OAuth](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2011/01/10/2-legged-vs-3-legged-oauth/). You can get some example code [here](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo), but its in PHP. You can also see a C# Example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/359144/Legged-OAuth-Authentication-in-NET-Csharp)

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this is an old question but I'm currently looking into the same thing.  From what I've found, using an embeded webBrowser as per SamFisher83's suggestion is "strongly discouraged".

I thought I'd share this guide from Google themselves.

[Link to Google OAuth 2.0 guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

No doubt the OP found a way of doing it, but this was one of the first links that came up via a google search on the subject and thought I'd share the link for any future reference.